# Identify the type of fallacy

Tags: logic

> "Mohan is a student and he is hardworking. Therefore, all students are hardworking."  Is the fallacy committed here that of converse accident or of composition?

From what I understand, it is the fallacy of converse accident as we are moving from the attribute a single case and applying the attribute to all the cases. However, the word 'all' creates a confusion here; does it mean that each and very student is hardworking, or that all students taken together as a class are hardworking?

Comment: This should be faulty generalization. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization

Comment: It means that each and every student is hardworking, as in $\forall x\left(\textsf{IsStudent}(x)\to\textsf{IsHardworking}(x)\right)$.

Comment: @Demosthene: and that your statement follows from Hardworking(M).

Comment: The only way a group of people can be said to be hard-working is if every person in the group is hard-working, so there is no confusion here. Anyway, in logic the word "all" should be considered a universal quantifier, so "all students are hard-working" is the same as "every student is hard-working".

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of [faulty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization) or [hasty generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization), where we apply to a whole set of individuals an attribute verified on one (or few) individual. Translated in the language of Predicate Logic:
$$\exists x\left(\textsf{IsStudent}(x)\land\textsf{IsHardworking}(x)\right)\to\forall x\left(\textsf{IsStudent}(x)\to\textsf{IsHardworking}(x)\right)$$
So if we observe of Mohan that he is a student and that he is hardworking, does this imply that every student must be hardworking? Not necessarily. In fact, you need to find only one student who is not hardworking to turn the above statement false. And of course, the statement is true if it is verified that all students are hardworking *or* if the only student is Mohan himself.